# "Cabal-2.4.1.0 failed during the configure step" when trying to install gtk2hs-buildtools

Tags: haskell, ubuntu-16.04, cabal-install

I'm trying to `cabal install gtk2hs-buildtools` but I'm receiving the error in a 'ParseResult.hs' file. I'm not sure if this is a bug or a local error.

I've ensured that the rc file has been properly updated to have `export PATH=$HOME/.cabal/bin:$PATH`

(the large spaces are from the formatting)

```
cabal install gtk2hs-buildtools
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring Cabal-2.4.1.0...
Failed to install Cabal-2.4.1.0
Build log ( /home/cuffaro/.cabal/logs/Cabal-2.4.1.0.log ):
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
Cabal-2.4.1.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
user error ('/usr/bin/ghc' exited with an error:

/tmp/cabal-tmp-6517/Cabal-                2.4.1.0/Distribution/Parsec/ParseResult.hs:32:0:
error: missing binary operator before token "("
#if MIN_VERSION_base(4,10,0)
^

/tmp/cabal-tmp-6517/Cabal-      2.4.1.0/Distribution/Parsec/ParseResult.hs:88:0:
error: missing binary operator before token "("
#if MIN_VERSION_base(4,10,0)
^
)
gtk2hs-buildtools-0.13.4.0 depends on Cabal-2.4.1.0 which failed to    install.
```

Comment: Just a guess, but I bet you need a newer version of cabal-install. I'm guessing yours is lacking support for custom-setup stanzas.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman following your advice, I ran `cabal install Cabal cabal-install` but I'm encountering the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the newly installed binary?  Correct paths? `hash -r`?

Comment: What does cabal --version say?

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman
cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.22.6.0
using version 1.22.5.0 of the Cabal library

@ThomasM.DuBuisson `hash -r` does not seem to resolve anything. I'll need to deliberate a little more, but I think my paths are correct. What more specific information would be helpful?

Comment: Looks like your PATH doesn't include the install location.

Comment: I know this may be a rudimentary question, but how can I determine the install location to test this as a solution? I'm new

Comment: @MattCuffaro If you installed via `cabal install` then the location should be `$HOME/.cabal/bin` which you can, arguably should, include in your PATH.  For a quick test you could make sure that binary is what's expected `$HOME/.cabal/bin/cabal --version`

Comment: If you're still having trouble, you could also try using Stack. (Note: biased recommendation, I'm one of the authors.) There are instructions available at: https://haskell-lang.org/get-started/linux I'd also recommend checking out the "next steps" section for how to get started using Stack. Also, there's a Gitter channel where you can ask follow up questions at: https://gitter.im/commercialhaskell/stack

Comment: I appreciate you following up. I had updated to the most recent Ubuntu (18.04) and it worked (updating resolved another python issue I was having).

Comment: Awesome, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 2):

My resolution was to update to 18.04. No issues now.